# How to select random from list while excluding the previous random choice?

Tags: python, list, random

I am trying to create a script that will allow me to play, from a list, a random christmas radio station using mpg123 upon button press. The problem I am running into is that, many times, the same radio station will play. I am messing around with lists, but having trouble getting it to work. I dont have the button wired just yet, so I am having the script pause and go again. Here are the stations so far..

```
station1 = "http://185.33.21.112:80/christmas_128"
station2 = "http://71.127.174.26:8020/hollyfm2"
station3 = "http://76.115.146.246:8128"
station4 = "http://85.25.217.22:8050/christmas"

station_list = [station1, station2, station3, station4]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a one line solution:

```py
chosen = station_list.pop(random.randrange(len(station_list)))
```

This picks a random index from the length of the list, `pop`s it out (removing it from the list) and assigns it to the `chosen` variable.

Additionally, defining string variables if you're just going to place them in a list is redundant, I'd do
`station_list = ['http://185.33.21.112:80/christmas_128', 'http://71.127.174.26:8020/hollyfm2', 'http://76.115.146.246:8128', 'http://85.25.217.22:8050/christmas']`

Comment: I was pretty much just writing the same answer. You beat me by 20 seconds. I suggest to also save the original list to be able to start again once the last station in the list have been popped.

Comment: @Karl There's a few suggestions on this post, hard to know what would be ideal without seeing the rest of the implementation.

Comment: I think you are missing a len(station_list)

Comment: @Karl - I did that by doing this: def radio_play():
    `global station_list
    chosen = station_list.pop(random.randrange(len(station_list)))
    print(chosen)
    radio_play = subprocess.call(["mplayer", chosen])
    length = len(station_list)
    if length < 1:
        station_list = [station1, station2, station3, station4]` It seems to work! Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

Simply shuffle the list and then iterate through the stations in order:

```
import random
random.shuffle(station_list)
for station in station_list:
    ...
```

Comment: I am not sure how I would be able to go through one at a time.

Comment: I gave you the iteration loop; where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution where every button press will switch to a random station that is not playing you could use this:

```py
import random

def non_repeating(src):
    seq = src[:]
    random.shuffle(seq)
    while True:
        item = seq[0]
        yield item
        seq = seq[1:]
        random.shuffle(seq)
        seq.append(item)

station_list = ['http://185.33.21.112:80/christmas_128', 'http://71.127.174.26:8020/hollyfm2', 'http://76.115.146.246:8128', 'http://85.25.217.22:8050/christmas']

g = non_repeating(station_list)

# The example here is to play 20 stations
for _ in range(20):
    print(next(g))
```

Comment: This looks like it would be helpful, but I am afraid that I am not quite understanding what is happening here (new to python and have 1 completed project :/).

Comment: g is a generator and every time ‘next(g)’ is called a value is returned from ‘yield item’. If you have a button event, you could call ‘next(g)’ to get a different station at random.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting something from a list, use del to remove it from the list.
Or keep a list of selected and re-run random if it is in the previously selected list.

```py
import random

station1 = "http://185.33.21.112:80/christmas_128"
station2 = "http://71.127.174.26:8020/hollyfm2"
station3 = "http://76.115.146.246:8128"
station4 = "http://85.25.217.22:8050/christmas"

station_list = [station1, station2, station3, station4]

while len(station_list):
    i_sel = random.randint(0, len(station_list)-1)
    sel = station_list[i_sel]
    del station_list[i_sel]
    print(sel)
```